Chrome (Version 127.0.6533.72 (Official Build) (arm64)) overlap of last request in network tab
I've recently updated Chrome to version 127.0.6533.72 (Official Build) (arm64), but I think it is existing since weeks, and I've noticed a peculiar issue in the Network tab of the Developer Tools. Specifically, the last request in the network log seems to be overlapped by the toolbar below, making it difficult to distinguish between the two.

If I click on the details, the overlap disapears. Anyone else having this issue?

Chrome Version: 127.0.6533.72 (Official Build) (arm64)
Operating System: macOs 14.5 (23F79)
Thank you!
